# I can't connect to internet through wired connection

Tags: networking, internet, wired

I'm new Ubuntu user. I just installed Ubuntu 15.10, my problem is like this:
I can connect to Internet through wifi without any problem, but when I turn off the wifi, I can't connect through wired connection.
I searched a lot but couldn't find how to fix the problem.

**Edit:**

Thank you for your help, but I still have problem. Here is the output from the `ifconfig` command:

```
$ ifconfig
enp5s0: Link  encap:Ethernet   HWaddr  28:d2:44:84:98:ed
        UP  BROADCAST  MULTICAST   MTU:1500     Metric:1
        RX  packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo: Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
        RX bytes:25921 (25.9 KB)  TX bytes:25921 (25.9 KB)
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, does the wired ethernet connection you are trying to use work with another computer?

If not, try switching the cable or port that it is connected to - e.g moving from a switch to the ports on the back of your router.

If you are sure that the wired connection does work, then there are a few things you could try:

- Firstly, open a new terminal and enter the command below, making sure that your ethernet cable is attached and wifi turned off

  ```
  ifconfig
  ```

  The output of this should show you all of the connected/active network adapters. one nearest the top should be named either 'eth0' or 'enp2s0' so similar. This should display an 'inet addr:192.168.0.#'. If you do not see this please edit your question with a copy of the output from the 'ifconfig' command.
- Secondly, enter the command below, into a new terminal:

  ```
  sudo ifconfig eth0 up
  ```

  With 'eth0' being edited depending on the output of 'ifconfig'

  This should start the ethernet (wired connection) adapter and provide you with network connection.